# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default(...)(...).daterangepicker is not a function when using jquery with react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, frontend

I am using a template for react js that has jquery in it. For jquery, i wrote script tags in index.html and jquery code in componentDidMount(). Now, it shows error for daterangepicker. I have included the js file for daterangepicker in script tags.
my index.html code:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />

  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap-spinner/bootstrap-spinner.js"></script> 
<script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script> 


<script src="js/theme.js"></script>
```

Also the react component with jquery is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import moment from 'moment';

import $ from 'jquery';
// const $ = window.$;
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

class Layout extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        // $(function() {
            'use strict';
             // Depart Date
             $('#busDepart').daterangepicker({
               singleDatePicker: true,
               minDate: moment(),
               autoUpdateInput: false,
               }, function(chosen_date) {
             $('#busDepart').val(chosen_date.format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
             });
        //    });
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
//....code remaining
```

Comment: hello there,
did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and didn't found any resource in the internet. At last what i noticed that you can not implement any library function using jquery into the react project. You should have maintain the react way that means you should use library of react.

first install daterangepicker using npm

> npm install react-datepicker --save

then Add this two line into your file where you want to add daterangepicker

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

And then into your class define you daterangepicker event code i used it in my way, take a look if helps you.

```
class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            startDate: '',
            endDate: ''
        };

        this.handleStateDateChange = this.handleStateDateChange.bind(this);
        this.handleEndDateChange = this.handleEndDateChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleStateDateChange(date){
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    }

    handleEndDateChange(date){
        this.setState({
            endDate: date
        });
    }
```

at the end into the render function just call the DatePicker module

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {/* Date Picker Start */}
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="Datecontent">
                        <label><b>Date Range Search</b></label>
                        <br />
                            <DatePicker
                                selected={this.state.startDate}
                                onChange={this.handleStateDateChange}
                                className='form-control'
                                placeholderText='Start Date'
                            />


                            <DatePicker
                                selected={this.state.endDate} 
                                onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}
                                className='form-control'
                                placeholderText='End Date'
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Date Picker End */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Thats it run the project Thank you .